# WiX: Uninstallable Patches

Tags: wix, windows-installer, patch

Following the suggestion in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22182126/3637487) answer I have a patch that suppresses the running of custom actions via the use of `PATCH` and `Not Installed` conditions.

Works great when installing the patch but I have the additional requirement that the patch needs to be uninstallable. This presents a problem because when our original product was authored we unfortunately did not take into account the possibility of future patching. My understanding of uninstalling patches is that Windows Installer basically re-runs the original package in `REINSTALL` mode. This is going to wreak havoc on the application configuration, as it requires a bunch of user-provided values for things such as IIS, config files, etc.

I have read that it's possible to re-cache the originally-installed package with an updated one that has correct conditioning in `InstallExecuteSequence` to skip actions if it's in a reinstall mode, but it seems risky/hacky. Are there any other ways around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That re-caching isn't as risky as it sounds, but it's a rare alternative to patching. You'd do it with a command line that has REINSTALL=ALL REINSTALLMODE=vomus.

It's rare because if you're going to rebuild the MSI to fix those conditions you may as well go all the way and do a major upgrade in which you can supply whatever fixes are in the patch as well as fixing the CA conditions to make the new product more easily patchable, including uninstalling patches.

Comment: Major upgrade would be the easiest route but we wanted to avoid having to have the user go through all the configuration dialogs again and the installer re-run ConfigureIIS, XmlFile, etc just for a few file changes. Thanks for your input!